# Is it acceptable to contact people from an old job interview and ask now if a job is still available?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process

Is it OK to contact people from an old job interview and ask if a job is still available? Last time I withdrew my application after the interview and before results were announced. I was from a different country and had some family issues but I withdrew with the message that I am not so interested in that project.

I noted that some positions remain unfilled for longer periods of time (several month to more than one year), because they cannot hire the right person, I suppose. In this case the time past is more than one year.

**Is it a good idea to contact the main member of the selection comittee (project leader) and ask directly if that particular job is still available?** For exmple, maybe they were not able to fill the position, or the hired person left etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is absolutely acceptable to contact a company you previously interviewed at to inquire if the position is still available.  However, dont be surprised if it is not.

Obviously, it wouldnt hurt to check the company's website to see what positions are open.  This is your best bet on seeing if the position is still available.

Comment: Thank you. And do you think it is okay to say something that my previous withdrawal was not my best decision/mistake? Or should I just directly ask on the job and show no remorse?

Comment: @user3624251 Just be honest.  Tell them you had family issues which are now no longer an issue.

Comment: I edited the question a bit. I said to them that I am withdrawing because I am not so interested in that project. I said I do not want to move into that field, to be more precise.

Comment: @user3624251 seriously?  instead of telling them the truth, you told them a lie.  Not just any lie, but you told  them you werent interested in the project or field.  honestly,  even if the position was still available, i would have serious doubts about hiring you.  Again, it cant hurt to ask if the position is still available and tell them you are interested, but if I were you, I wouldnt hold my breath.

Comment: @user3624251 and now be honest. Tell them that you did not want to discuss private matters and therefore told them this lie. They might believe you.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it's acceptable to ask (can't do any harm) but don't be surprised if you don't get the job, even if it's available.

Definitely ask, they may ask you to resubmit the application and interview, but just be aware that you have a slight black mark against your name as a flake.

You've said in the comments:

> I said to them that I am withdrawing because I am not so interested in that project. I said I do not want to move into that field, to be more precise.

If this were true, you would not be a good fit for the job, as it happens, you lied to them instead. Even if your real reason is a really good one, it's unlikely to look good for you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  It's part of networking.

I always keep in touch with contacts.  I don't approach with a "hey, is the job still open?"  This is too direct and will (at least in my experience) not have the result you're looking for.

Instead I call to discuss the industry, ask for recommendations, etc.  Show that you've done your research.  And how you help them meet their business goals.

There is a headhunter - Nick Corcodilos - who writes on the employment system.  https://www.asktheheadhunter.com/

I've used his system for my last two positions.  Do your research.  Get in front of decision makers.  Show them how you help them (and company) do there job and make money.

Good luck.